# Firebase nested ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure -

```
 {
      "linking" : {
        "shift-assign" : { // for every shift its assigned users
          "key1" : {
            "111" : true,
            "222" : true
          },
          "key2" : {
            "111" : true
          }
        },
        "user-assign" : { // for every user its assigned shifts
          "111" : {
            "key1" : true,
            "key2" : true
          },
          "222" : {
            "key1" : true
          }
        }
      },
      "shifts" : {
        "20191117" : {
          "key1" : {
            "endTime" : "00:00",
            "numOfEmps" : 3,
            "startTime" : "00:00",
            "wage" : 0
          },
          "key2" : {
            "endTime" : "00:00",
            "numOfEmps" : 1,
            "startTime" : "00:00",
            "wage" : 0
          }
        }
      },
      "users" : {
        "111" : {
          "id" : "111",
          "password" : "111"
          },
        "222" : {
          "id" : "222",
          "password" : "222"
        },
        "99999" : {
          "id" : "99999",
          "password" : "123",
        }
      }
    }
```

Where a user can be assigned to several shifts and a shift can contain several users.

I'm currently trying to fetch all of the users assigned to a certain shift.

So the idea was attaching a `ValueEventListener` to `linking/shift-assign/{shift-key}`, run a loop and for every `user-key` , reference `users/{user-key}` and attach an inner `ValueEventListener` to read user object and add it to a `userList`.

Something like this :

```
mDatabase.child("linking/shift-assign").child(shiftKey)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            mDatabase.child("users").child(ds.getKey())
                                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                                            mUser user = dataSnapshot2.getValue(mUser.class);
                                            userList.add(user);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                                    });
                        }
                        adapter = new UsersAssignedAdapter(UsersAssignedActivity.this, userList);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
```

I debugged it and noticed that the `for` loop is finished before the inner `ValueEventListener` is called, which is why I'm getting an empty list in my adapter. I'm guessing this is due to its asynchronous behavior.

So my question is - is there any way I can query all user ids and for each one perform another query?

Comment: add a log to `ds.getKey()` and to `user` variable

Comment: add a log? how would that help?